# Installing Pycharm Python IDE in Raspbian

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

Can anyone please tell me how to install Pycharm - Python IDE into Raspbian.
There is a default IDE called 'Thonny' installed.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to go to https://draculatheme.com/jetbrains/
You'll have several links to Github try to look at them and learn how to install the "theme" that you want on PyCharm. But you can change your *color scheme* on PyCharm by going on the left top corner: 
- File --> settings and Appearance on windows
- PyCharm CE --> Preferences and Appearance on Mac

Best Luck! Zelandini